# How to change the display icon of module in OMNet++ with c++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

Is there a method to change the display icon of a module or simple module in omnet++ with c++? help me please if there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the icon (and other visual properties) at runtime. An example:

```
cDisplayString& displayString = getDisplayString();
displayString.setTagArg("i", 0, "device/pc3");
```

If you intend to change the icon of the *parent* module, use this example:

```
cDisplayString& displayString = getParentModule()->getDisplayString();
displayString.setTagArg("i", 0, "device/pc3");
```

The `device/pc3` is an image filename existing in `images` subfolder.

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:changing-displaystrings-at-runtime)